# PPPoE Performance Test

Tags: router, performance

I'm looking for some tool or a way to execute performance test with pppoe account.
*simulate PPPoE sessions and traffic*.

Example: 
I have a **PowerEdge R420** running a VYOS, I was wondering, how is the performance with 4k PPPoE sessions and each of them traffing 25mb/s.

Is it there possible?

Comment: You've got 100 Gbit/s bandwidth to test with? Or is it mbs = millibit/s?

Comment: down/upstream are 3,125 megabytes, sometimes it confused me :)